# Crear un TRIGGER en mi archivo python para actualizar base de datos

Tags: python, mysql, sql, script, trigger

utilizo pandas y sqlalchemy. Lo que hace mi script de python hasta ahora es extraer cierta información de una base muy grande, luego esa información la paso a mi base que utilizo para la pagina. Hasta ahora lo estoy haciendo sin el trigger y algunas veces me agrega duplicados. Entonces quisiera saber si con un trigger eso se solucionaria.

Omito parte del código donde están las conexiones con información pero dejo una parte que seria la lógica para insertar la info.

## Obtener los datos existentes de la tabla

```
existing_data_query = "SELECT * FROM cobranzas_cliente"
existing_data = pd.read_sql(existing_data_query, engine)

for table_name, table_content in tables_content.items():
    # Reemplazar los valores "NULL" por None
    table_content = table_content.fillna(0)
    # Reemplazar los valores en blanco o espacios en blanco por 0
    table_content = table_content.replace(['', ' '], 0)
    # Crear una nueva tabla temporal con las filas únicas
    table_content_unique = table_content.drop_duplicates(subset=columns_to_update)

    for row in table_content_unique.itertuples(index=False):
        condition_values = [f"{column} = '{getattr(row, column)}'" for column in 
 columns_to_update]
        condition_query = f"SELECT * FROM cobranzas_cliente WHERE {' AND 
'.join(condition_values)}"
        existing_row = pd.read_sql(condition_query, engine)

        if not existing_row.empty:
           # Actualizar el registro existente
           update_values = [f"{column} = '{getattr(row, column)}'" for column in 
columns_to_update]
            update_query = f"UPDATE cobranzas_cliente SET {', '.join(update_values)} 
WHERE {' AND '.join(condition_values)}"
            engine.execute(update_query)
```

Comment: Pues puede ser tan simple como tener un CONSTRAINT UNIQUE en la tabla sobre un campo para que no se dupliquen valores de, digamos, el ID del registro o algo así. Un trigger sobre la tabla A no puede efectuar otra operación sobre la misma tabla A, si es lo que estás pensando.

Comment: 1. Los triggers no sirven para evitar duplicados. 2. Si hablas de trigger a nivel de base de datos, usualmente lo que está disponible para el trigger son  los recursos de la propia base de datos. Nada impide hacer otras cosas, como mandar a insertar un registro a una base de datos remota, pero no es lo más aconsejable, por temas de estabilidad y desempeño. Aún así, la respuesta a la pregunta es: No se puede, ya que no puedes hacer un trigger en un archivo python (repito, si hablamos de triggers a nivel de base de datos). Si hablas de otro tipo de trigger, bien valdría que lo aclares.